# How to disable arrow keys in ListView control in VBA with Excel

Tags: excel, vba, listview

I am writing a VBA application with Excel.  I need to use a ListView control because this seems to be the only way of using different colours for different rows that are displayed in the list.  I need to enable/disable buttons on the form depending on which type of row is selected in the Listview control.  If I use the mouse to click on the rows, this works perfectly - I have a Listview1_Click routine which looks like this:

```
Private Sub Listview1_Click()

DeleteSelected.Enabled = False
EditSelected.Enabled = False
If comspec(Listview1.SelectedItem.Index) <> "HbA1c" Then
    DeleteSelected.Enabled = True
    EditSelected.Enabled = True
End If

End Sub
```

However, if I use the up and down arrow keys, the focus appears to move from one row to the next in the ListView control but of course the buttons stay the same.  I have come to the conclusion that the only way of getting around this is to disable the arrow keys in the ListView control.  There doesn't appear to be a ListView event that captures arrow keys though - I have tried using ListView1_KeyDown as follows:

```
Private Sub Listview1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal shift As Integer)

If KeyCode = vbKeyUp or KeyCode = vbKeyDown Then KeyCode = vbNull

End Sub
```

but it throws a compile error - I don't think the KeyDown event is recognised with the ListView control.  Any help would be gratefully received.

Many thanks.

Comment: What about the mouse, and the mouse wheel, and the tab key?  Don't they also affect this?

Comment: Mouse wheel doesn't affect anything, and the tab key just navigates around the different controls within the form (i.e. from ListView to buttons and back again).  It is just the arrow keys that are potentially causing a problem here.

Comment: ListView and TreeView as non built-in ActiveX controls, cannot be used in 64 bit versions of Office. Additional hint: You might want to see a well explained alternative of *JKP*, a *professional* application developper in an interesting article [MSForms All VBA TreeView](https://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/treeview.asp); though offering a professional version, focus is laid upon a free demo version using classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the right signature of vba keydown function.

It worked with that signature:

```
Private Sub ListView1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = vbKeyUp Or KeyCode = vbKeyLeft Or KeyCode = vbKeyDown Or KeyCode = vbKeyRight Then KeyCode = vbNull
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect - thankyou very much for your help, it now works!